# How to fix this type mismatch?

Tags: scala, collections, iterable

Suppose I am defining `zipWith` like this:

```
def zipWith[A](f:(A, A) => A)(xs:Iterable[A], ys:Iterable[A]): Iterable[A] =
  (xs, ys).zipped map f
```

Now I'd like to use for zipping matrices like that:

```
type Matrix = Vector[Vector[Int]]

val zipMatrix: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Matrix => Matrix => Matrix = f =>
  zipWith(zipWith(f))
```

However I got an error:

```
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
found   : (Iterable[Iterable[Int]], Iterable[Iterable[Int]]) => Iterable[Iterable[Int]]
required: Matrix => (Matrix => Matrix)
(which expands to)  scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Vector[Int]] => (scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Vector[Int]] => scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Vector[Int]])
```

Why doesn't `Vector[Vector[Int]]` match `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]` ? How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
def zipWith[A] (f:(A => A => A))(xs:Vector[A])(ys:Vector[A]): Vector[A] =
  (xs, ys).zipped.map {case (x, y) => f (x)(y)}

val zipMatrix: (Int => Int => Int) => (Matrix => Matrix => Matrix) = f =>
  zipWith(zipWith(f))
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to get a more generic solution. The more generic the better :)

Comment: Ok, then maybe you should define Matrix type more 'generic'? type Matrix = Iterable[Iterable[Int]]?

Comment: Probably. But what is wrong with `Vector[Vector[Int]]` ? Suppose I cannot change the `Matrix` type.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it is just more general than your desired (Iterable[A]) result type of zipWith,

Comment: `Vector` is more general than `Iterable` ?